# Converting string timestamp to Python datetime (was: how to properly convert char into float or double in Python)

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

Here I have string like this `"1322485986.672901000"`, data type is string which represents unixtime. I want to convert it into datetime in Python.

The way I used is `date = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(row[0]))` row[0] represents value like this `1322485986.672901000`, since I have several rows. The convert result is wrong, it only calculates the digits before the dot. So the date after conversion is like 2011-11-28 13:53:23.6729

I think the problem is `float(row[0])`, but I don't know how to solve this problem, or does anyone know how to convert unixtime to datetime in a better way?

Many thanks!

Now the result I got is 2011-11-28 14:13:06.672901

But when using an online converter, the result is 2011-11-28 13:13:06

Comment: What would be the correct result?

Comment: since this result keeps . 6729 in the original string, it means it only use the first 10 digits to calculate the datetime. The correct result would be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Looks right to me. You seem to have lost a small amount of precision in the seconds (.672901000 to .6729), but even that might be only the output formatting.

Comment: So you want to ignore the fractional part? You're being very unclear, please post the exact result you want.

Comment: The part before the decimal point is seconds in the unix epoch; the part after the decimal point is fractions of a second. If you want to see yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, use `int(float(row[0]))`.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I don't think use int is a good idea, since I can get the correct time using a tool online which is different from the time I got

Comment: @TimPietzcker Sorry, I just posted the correct result

Comment: The hour difference you're getting is due to a time zone/daylight savings/summer time issue, not due to the int. Note that in my answer below the hour is yet again different because I'm in the US Pacific Time zone. What online converter are you using?

Comment: The online converter should not matter.  You're completely right about the timezone issue.  See Geoff Gerrietts' answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your one-hour difference in the current result is likely the consequence of time zone application.

You can supply an explicit time zone if you need to -- the docs on [tzinfo objects](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) can steer you straight on creating your time zone object, and once it's created, you just pass in the argument:

```
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta

timestamp = "1322485986.672901000"

class UTC(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
         return timedelta(0)
    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"
    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)


d1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(timestamp), UTC())
print d1
```

This code prints 2011-11-28 13:13:06.672901+00:00 for me.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you want to produce UTC time from the unix timestamp, you can simply use datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(timestamp)).

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = "1322485986.672901000"

d1 = datetime.fromtimestamp( float(timestamp) )
print d1

d2 = datetime.fromtimestamp( int(float(timestamp) ) )
print d2
```

Yields:

```
2011-11-28 05:13:06.672901
2011-11-28 05:13:06
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# timestamp to time tuple in UTC
    timestamp = 1226527167.595983
    time_tuple = time.gmtime(timestamp)
    print repr(time_tuple)

# timestamp to time tuple in local time
    timestamp = 1226527167.595983
    time_tuple = time.localtime(timestamp)
    print repr(time_tuple)
```